# Is access by pointer so expensive?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, pointers

I've a `Process()` function that is called very heavy within my DLL (VST plugin) loaded in a DAW (Host software), such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nFrames; i++) {
    // ...

    for (int voiceIndex = 0; voiceIndex < PLUG_VOICES_BUFFER_SIZE; voiceIndex++) {
        Voice &voice = pVoiceManager->mVoices[voiceIndex];
        if (voice.mIsPlaying) {
            for (int envelopeIndex = 0; envelopeIndex < ENVELOPES_CONTAINER_NUM_ENVELOPE_MANAGER; envelopeIndex++) {
                Envelope &envelope = pEnvelopeManager[envelopeIndex]->mEnvelope;
                envelope.Process(voice);
            }           
        }
    }
}

void Envelope::Process(Voice &voice) {
    if (mIsEnabled) {
        // update value
        mValue[voice.mIndex] = (mBlockStartAmp[voice.mIndex] + (mBlockStep[voice.mIndex] * mBlockFraction[voice.mIndex]));
    }
    else {
        mValue[voice.mIndex] = 0.0;
    }
}
```

It basically takes 2% of CPU within the Host (which is nice).

Now, if I slightly change the code to this (which basically are increments and assignment):

```
void Envelope::Process(Voice &voice) {
    if (mIsEnabled) {
        // update value
        mValue[voice.mIndex] = (mBlockStartAmp[voice.mIndex] + (mBlockStep[voice.mIndex] * mBlockFraction[voice.mIndex]));

        // next phase
        mBlockStep[voice.mIndex] += mRate;
        mStep[voice.mIndex] += mRate;
    }
    else {
        mValue[voice.mIndex] = 0.0;
    }

    // connectors
    mOutputConnector_CV.mPolyValue[voice.mIndex] = mValue[voice.mIndex];
}
```

CPU go to 6/7%  (note, those var don't interact with other part of codes, or at least I think so).

The only reason I can think is that access to pointer is heavy? How can I reduce this amount of CPU?

Those arrays are basic double "pointer" arrays (the most lighter C++ `container`):

```
double mValue[PLUG_VOICES_BUFFER_SIZE];
double mBlockStartAmp[PLUG_VOICES_BUFFER_SIZE];
double mBlockFraction[PLUG_VOICES_BUFFER_SIZE];
double mBlockStep[PLUG_VOICES_BUFFER_SIZE];
double mStep[PLUG_VOICES_BUFFER_SIZE];

OutputConnector mOutputConnector_CV;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use a `struct VoiceParameters { double mValue; double mBlockStartAmp; /* etc */ }; VoiceParameters voiceParameters[PLUG_VOICES_BUFFER_SIZE];` instead, which would improve cache-locality for everything indexed using the same index (e.g. `voice.mIndex`).

Comment: arrays are not pointers

Comment: It definitely shouldn't make that much difference. I'd double-check your measurement and code. Are you using release mode? Also worth looking at the generated assembly.

Comment: Your second code does 3 assignments where you first code did 1 ... seems reasonable for it to triple the CPU use?

Comment: @M.M: is assignments so heavy?

Comment: *the most lighter C++ container* Tell to whoever told you this that he's wrong.

Comment: @M.M: as jotik shows, when the three values are adjacent, you might still be writing a single cache line per index. Three assignments isn't necessarily slower, let alone three times slower.

Comment: On a design note: since those 5 arrays clearly hold values for every `Voice`, why don't the voices themselves hold these values? Why is there an array outside `Voice`? Of course, there is code outside the code shown which might justify that particular decision, but it is remarkable.

Comment: to everybody: another funny thing. If I set some variable "public" instead of "private", I gain 3% of CPU :O Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking that "pointer arrays" are the lightest containers. but CPU's don't think in terms of containers. They just read and write values through pointers.

The problem here might very well be that *you* know that two containers do not overlap (there are no "sub-containers"). But the CPU might not be told that by the compiler. Writing to `mBlockStep` might affect `mBlockFraction`. The compiler doesn't have run-time values, so it needs to handle the case where it does. This will mean introducing more memory reads, and less caching of values in registers.

Comment: What's your suggestion so? Using STL containers?

Comment: I am assuming that mStep, mBlockStartAmp etc are arrays and not references. Would this not mean that the compiler is free to assume no aliasing?

Comment: @RichardHodges: That probably depends on the exact definition of them, and also on the visibility to the compiler.

Comment: the definitions are written in OP's post, they are indeed arrays and I don't think there is any aliasing

Comment: @MSalters the exact definition of them has been posted by the OP. They are arrays - i.e. discrete objects, guaranteed not to be aliased. I think you're on the wrong track here.

Comment: The more I look at it, the more it seems that there is simply more writes on slower version, with the final write dependent on a branch

Comment: @PasserBy: So, are they on the stack, or class members, or globals?

Comment: Why are you asking me? If you want to make a point, make it. I don't expect a 3~4x performance hit is due to some variables being global, and needless to say, your answer doesn't reflect your concern.

Comment: @PasserBy: Because you're claiming that the exact definitions are in the OP's post. If they were, my question would have been answered. Globals can't alias, other variables can.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pack all the data items in a structure and create an array of structure. I would simply use a `vector`.
2. In `Process` function get the single element out of this vector, and use its parameters. At the cache-line/instruction level, all items would be (efficiently) brought into local cache (L1), as the data element (members of struct) as contiguous. Use reference or pointer of struct type to avoid copying.
3. Try to use integer data-types unless `double` is needed.

**EDIT**:

```
struct VoiceInfo 
{ 
   double mValue; 
   ...
}; 
VoiceInfo voices[PLUG_VOICES_BUFFER_SIZE];
// Or vector<VoiceInfo> voices;
```

...

```
void Envelope::Process(Voice &voice) 
{
     // Get the object (by ref/pointer)
     VoiceInfo& info = voices[voice.mIndex];
     // Work with reference 'info'
  ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `Use reference or pointer of struct type to avoid copying.`?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Tried with Pack/cache-line: the result is the same! Also using float instead of double. Nothing change. The optimization should be elsewhere...